# Best data structure for this problem?

Tags: java, hashtable, lookup, comparator, treemap

I am using Java for this program, and I currently have a situation where I want to add key/value pairs to a table with integer keys, like

```
add (1, "Bobby")
add (6, "Sue")
add (3, "Mary")
add (8, "John")
add (15, "Joe")
```

So naturally I want to do something like a hashtable, but when I do a lookup, if it doesn't find the exact value, I would like it to return the nearest key that isn't greater than the requested key.

So for example, if I lookup 7, it should return "Sue", but if I lookup 9, it should return "John"

I'm hoping to use one of the java util classes (HashTable, TreeMap, etc) but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TreeMap from the collections library provides the functionality you're looking for

```
TreeMap<Integer,String> tree = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
tree.put (1, "Bobby");
tree.put(6, "Sue");
tree.put (3, "Mary");
tree.put (8, "John");
tree.put (15, "Joe");
System.out.println(tree.floorEntry(7)); // Sue
System.out.println(tree.floorEntry(9)); // John
```

Answer (score 7):

[NavigableMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this using sql something like:

```
select top 1 * from hashTable where keyColumnId >= @passedValueId
```

would work.

Comment: Anyway to do it in java? The sql overhead is probably a bit much for this particular thing. Thank you though!

Comment: I think that @Eugen Constantin Dinca's answer is a good basis for a java only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you mostly read data from the structure and insert rarely you could use a trivial sorted array and do a binary search. Can't get much simpler or simpler if you're worried about search performance. Now not that great if you regularly update the structure - then you'll have to use something more complicated.

Also I think - but not totally sure - wouldn't a binary tree work just as well? Search for the position where the correct node should be and use its predecessor if the value isn't found.